# can't initialise/detect 16550A UART at unusual io port address

Tags: linux, drivers, linux-kernel

I've got a board based on the Vortex86DX CPU which is an x86 based microcontroller. It has five 16550A UARTS, four (COM1-COM4) of which are at the usual io port addresses (0x3f8, 0x2f8, 0x3e8, 0x2e8) but the fifth (COM9) is at 0x010, irq 9.

[Vortex86DX](http://www.dmp.com.tw/tech/vortex86dx/)

The first four UARTS are detected, I have no problem with them. The problem is that I can't get the fifth one (COM9) to work in Linux. COM9 works in a stand alone DOS application, but I can't even detect it from Linux.

What I've done so far:

- added my extra UART to [/drivers/tty/serial/8250/](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/8250/)
- enabled DEBUG_AUTOCONF in [/drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250.c) so I can see when and which addresses are being probed.
- editted [/arch/x86/kernel/setup.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/setup.c) because io port 0x010 overlapped an existing region reserved for dma1

Result: the kernel failed to probe the UART at address 0x010

So I wrote an io port probing utility to directly read from io port 0x010, and I could not detect any 16550A registers in the 0x010 to 0x017 region. It appears there is nothing there. I have been trying to write and read back data from the scratch register (offset +7), but I get nothing at address 0x017.

The datasheet for the CPU doesn't say much. It indicates there is a control bit in a Southbridge register that does "something" for COM9. I wrote a PCI utility that wrote to this bit, but it didn't seem to enable the COM port or change anything when I did the io port probing.

Any help would be appreciated at this point!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you've gone to all the trouble to change the kernel source code to add support for this nonstandard serial I/O port and IRQ. The `setserial(8)` program should be able to configure it for you. Something like this:

```
# setserial ttyS4 address 0x10 irq 9
```

See [the Linux Serial HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO.html) for more details.

Comment: Nope, setserial doesn't work. The kernel still does the same autoconfig and scanning as setserial does.

`# setserial /dev/ttyS4 port 0x10 irq 9 uart 165
50A`

`ttyS4: LSR safety check engaged!`

Comment: An attempt to do a setserial autoconfig fails with:
ttyS4: autoconf (0x0010, 0x  (null)): IER test failed (0f, 0f) type=16550A
ttyS4: LSR safety check engaged!
ttyS4: LSR safety check engaged!

Which is what the kernel fails with as well.

Comment: If you look in the Serial HOWTO I pointed you to for "LSR safety check" you find that it means there is no serial port at that address. (It can also mean the UART has a buggy implementation, but that's probably not what's going on here.) You've run into the limits of the "Linux" part of the problem, so I suggest you re-post this question on electronics.SE to chase the low-level parts. The programming guide on the page you point to is near-useless for answering this, but maybe you'll get lucky and find someone who has programmed this SoC before.

Comment: I've since got the UART part working. Now I'm working on getting the Linux part working. My driver enables the correct settings in the Southbridge now, but Linux doesn't associate the /dev/ttyS4 with a tty. e.g. `# stty -F /dev/ttyS4 9600
stty: /dev/ttyS4: Input/output error`

Comment: Just to add. Linux detects my COM9 as ttyS4 in dmesg. e.g. `serial8250.11: ttyS4 at I/O 0x10 (irq = 9) is a 16550A`. udev/mdev will automatically create a node for it in /dev. So AFAIK the kernel knows about this node, but it doesn't seem to work as a tty device. e.g. `# picocom -b 9600 /dev/ttyS4 ... FATAL: failed to add device /dev/ttyS4: Filedes is not a tty`. Possibly there's a problem in my driver, but it all looks fairly straight forward how I am supposed to add a basic 8250 compatible device.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that either the BIOS or Linux disables the COM9 port in the Southbridge registers.

Registers:

- "Internal UART9 Control Register" must be reset to its default value of: 0x00810010
- "On-Chip Device Control Register" must have bit 9 cleared to re-enable COM9.

I don't know why or where these are disabled.

When I set them to sane values in my device driver I was able to detect the COM9 UART.

Linux requires a new x86 chip type for the Vortex86DX. It is not 100% compatible.